# Getting http chunked response with Tcp

Tags: c#, http, stream, tcpclient, networkstream

I would like to know how can be read an http response with Transfer-Encoding chunked.
I wrote an example of what I am doing. One problem I came across with this is that `clientStream.DataAvailable` returns `false` even if there is more content left to read but not still available on the stream.
Other suggestions about the way I am approaching this are welcome:

```
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("www.google.com", 80);

string request = "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
request += "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
request += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0\r\n";
request += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
request += "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n";
request += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n";
request += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

byte[] requestBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
clientStream.Write(requestBuffer, 0, requestBuffer.Length);

// Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable.
if (clientStream.CanRead)
{
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

    // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
    do
    {
        numberOfBytesRead = clientStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);

        response.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
    }
    while (clientStream.DataAvailable);
}

clientStream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();

Console.Write(response.ToString());
```

Thank you in advance.